# ReactJS not passing updated State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

So I'm new to React, I'm trying to pass the data after fetching with axios to Component:

**index.js**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { pokemon: null, errorMsg: '' };
  componentDidMount() {
    api
      .get('', {
        params: {
          limit: 50,
          offset: showrandom(),
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        const temporary = res.data.results;
        const details = { pokemon: [] };
        temporary.forEach((e) => {
          api
            .get('/' + e.name)
            .then((res) => details.pokemon.push(res.data))
            .catch((e) => console.log(e));
        });
        this.setState({ pokemon: details.pokemon });
      })
      .catch((e) => this.setState({ errorMsg: e }));
  }
  render() {
    if (this.state.pokemon) {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <div
            className="container-fluid"
            style={{ textAlign: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', marginBottom: '5em' }}
          >
            <img alt="logo" src="logo" />
            <p>by: Ihsan Fajar Ramadhan</p>
          </div>
          <div className="ui five column grid" style={{ padding: '2em' }}>
            <Cards data={this.state.pokemon} />
          </div>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <div className="ui" style={{ textAlign: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', marginBottom: '5em' }}>
            <img alt="logo" src="logo" />
            <p>by: Ihsan Fajar Ramadhan</p>
          </div>
          <div className="ui" style={{ textAlign: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <i className="compass loading icon massive blue"></i>
            <p className="ui text blue">Loading...</p>
          </div>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

**Card.js**

```js
import React from 'react';

const Card = (props) => {
  let pokemon = props.data.map((pokemon, i) => {
    return (
      <div className="column" key={i}>
        <div className="ui fluid card">
          <a className="image" href="/">
            <img alt="nama" src={pokemon.sprites.front_default} />
          </a>
          <div className="content" style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
            <a className="header" href="/">
              {pokemon.species.name}{' '}
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });
  if (props.data.length > 0) {
    return <>{pokemon}</>;
  } else {
    return <>fetching</>;
  }
};

export default Card;
```

The loading screen rendered successfully, and after the `pokemon` state updated it passes the condition where `if(this.state.pokemon)` which means the state has been updated, then it tries to render the element with  component. But the problem is the data props to  component is not passed yet, and it renders "fetching" instead `{pokemon}`. I've been searching for solution but I'm stuck. The strange part is that when I changed  content (adding or deleting word), the data is passed to the Component.

Comment: Have you logged `props.data` in the Card.js component? Does it have the right structure, are you able to see the log well?

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you describe is the case when `this.state.pokemon` is an empty array. `[]` is truthy, but its length is `0`, the exact conditions that cause `fetching` to be rendered. Can you show the part where you load the data and call setState?

Comment: I have updated this code, and i have cosoled this.state.pokemon it returns the list of pokemons, also the result from console.log in Card.js returns the same data. The initial value of this.state.pokemon is null, so when it's updated it should render <Card /> element.

Comment: There's the problem: a `forEach` loop doesn't wait for async code inside, only a for loop does, and you haven't even used `await`. When you call `this.setState({ pokemon: details.pokemon });`, none of the api calls has finished yet, and it's still `[]`, exactly what causes the behavior you observe.

Comment: To solve this, you can also use `Promise.all()` to run all requests in parallel, then call setState in the `.then` callback. A very simple way to do debugging is inserting `<pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}</pre>`, that way you will see the actual content of `this.state`, as opposed to console.log output that might not reflect what's actually in there.

Comment: Alright I will try it, thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, thank you to Chris G for the hint in the comment.

> There's the problem: a forEach loop doesn't wait for async code inside, only a for loop does, and you haven't even used await. When you call this.setState({ pokemon: details.pokemon });, none of the api calls has finished yet, and it's still [], exactly what causes the behavior you observe.

So here is my solution:

```
  async loadApi(){
    const temp= await api.get('',{
      params:{
        limit:50,
        offset:showrandom()
      }
    });
    const pokemon=[];
    for(let i=0; i<temp.data.results.length; i++){
      await api.get('/'+temp.data.results[i].name)
      .then(res => pokemon.push(res.data))
    }
    this.setState({pokemon:pokemon});
    return pokemon;
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.loadApi();
  }
```